# How to put dates on x axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Let's consider data :

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close
```

I want to plot apple variable using ggplot, so :

```
ggplot()+aes(x=1:length(apple), y = apple)+geom_line()
```

[image]

However I don't know how to put dates on x axis instead of number of observation. Dates are stored in AAPL data frame :

```
head(AAPL)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2013-01-02  19.77929  19.82143 19.34393   19.60821   560518000      17.06525
2013-01-03  19.56714  19.63107 19.32143   19.36071   352965200      16.84985
2013-01-04  19.17750  19.23679 18.77964   18.82143   594333600      16.38050
2013-01-07  18.64286  18.90357 18.40000   18.71071   484156400      16.28414
2013-01-08  18.90036  18.99607 18.61607   18.76107   458707200      16.32798
2013-01-09  18.66071  18.75036 18.42822   18.46786   407604400      16.07279
```

But I don't know how to extract those dates. Do you hany any idea how it can be done ?

Comment: This is not a minimal reproducible verifiable example: cf. [mcve]

Comment: Could you please explain more why you think my question does not match requirments ? I read what you sent and I don't know exactly what do you mean by 'minimal reproducible verifable example'

Comment: My comment is no longer since you fixed/editef the question afterwards.Not important anyways since you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `zoo` object, the dates are stored in custom attributes, but that won't work easily with ggplot.

```
class(apple)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

You can actually access those dates with the `zoo::index` function:

```
head(zoo::index(apple))
[1] "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-01-07" "2013-01-08" "2013-01-09"
```

Another approach is to convert to a data frame which will place the dates into the row names and then convert those row names to a column with `tibble::rownames_to_column`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
apple %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Date") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = AAPL.Close)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `autoplot.zoo` as shown below. Replace `Cl` with `Ad` if you want the adjusted close.

See `?autoplot.zoo` for more info.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL")
autoplot(Cl(AAPL))
```

It would be possible to customize the X axis, e.g.

```
autoplot(Cl(AAPL)) + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y", breaks = "year")
```

but the default without that may be sufficient.

Here is the output using the default.

[image: screenshot]